# Why can't I get the value from list in javascript which passed from C# asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, arraylist

This the code in C#, `GetCityNameArray` returns a list

```
   [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static  List<NegaraLibrary.Model.User.AdminUser> GetCityNameArray(       List<NegaraLibrary.Model.User.AdminUser> cities)
    {
        load();
        return adminuserlist;
    }
```

And this the Javascript code:

```
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
   <script>
    function GetCityNameArray() {
        var cities = new Array();
        var city = {};
        city.AdminUserName = "2000";
        city.AdminUserEmail = "safda";
        city.AdminUserID = 55;
        city.AdminUserPassword = "5555s";
        city.AdminUserTypeID = 1;
        city.CreatedOn = "12/7/2015";
        city.ModifiedOn = "12/7/2015";
        city.IsActive = true;
        cities[0] = city;
        city = {};
        city.AdminUserName = "2000";
        city.AdminUserEmail = "safda";
        city.AdminUserID = 55;
        city.AdminUserPassword = "5555s";
        city.AdminUserTypeID = 1;
        city.CreatedOn = "12/7/2015";
        city.ModifiedOn = "12/7/2015";
        city.IsActive = true;
        cities[1] = city;
        PageMethods.GetCityNameArray(cities, OnSuccessGetCityNameArray);
    }
    function OnSuccessGetCityNameArray(response)
    {
        alert(response.length);
        for (var i in response)
        {
            alert(response[i].AdminUserPassword + "," + response[i].AdminUserEmail + "," + response[i].AdminUserName + "," +   response[i].AdminUserID + "," + response[i].AdminUserTypeID);
        }
    }
  </script>
```

When the arraylist is passed from C# Javascript it shows as undefined in alert box.
When I try to get the length of passed array I get incredible number. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
function OnSuccessGetCityNameArray(response)
    {
response = JSON.parse(response);
        alert(response.length);
        for (var i in response)
        {
            alert(response[i].AdminUserPassword + "," + response[i].AdminUserEmail + "," + response[i].AdminUserName + "," +   response[i].AdminUserID + "," + response[i].AdminUserTypeID);
        }
    }
```